# Python - How to get an item out of a list of dicts?

Tags: python, json

Right now (If I'm not wrong) I have a list of dicts with some information; I want to get an specific item out of the list but I am having a problem to reach the item that I want; this is what I'm trying:

```
stats = requests.get("https://lan.api.pvp.net/api/lol/lan/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/24244/"
                     "summary?season=SEASON2016&api_key=").json()

pprint([d['playerStatSummaries'] for d in stats if 'playerStatSummaryType' in d])
```

I tried that by watching some examples; it may work but maybe I'm doing in the wrong way, the output of that is just a "[ ]" the request has this information:

```
"summonerId": 24244,
"playerStatSummaries": [

    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "CAP5x5",
        "wins": 20,
        "modifyDate": 1453305771000,
        "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalChampionKills": 308,
            "totalMinionKills": 4985,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 36,
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 466,
            "totalAssists": 255
        }
    },
    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "CoopVsAI",
        "wins": 34,
        "modifyDate": 1453305771000,
        "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalChampionKills": 394,
            "totalMinionKills": 2741,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 57,
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 146,
            "totalAssists": 336
        }
    },
    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "CoopVsAI3x3",
        "wins": 1,
        "modifyDate": 1453305771000,
        "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalChampionKills": 6,
            "totalMinionKills": 69,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 2,
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 0,
            "totalAssists": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "RankedTeam3x3",
        "wins": 0,
        "losses": 0,
        "modifyDate": 1353893998000,
        "aggregatedStats": { }
    },
    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "RankedTeam5x5",
        "wins": 0,
        "losses": 0,
        "modifyDate": 1354061714000,
        "aggregatedStats": { }
    }
```

Let's say that I want to access the information of "CoopVsAI" which is the second one; from that I want to access the "totalChampionKills"; how can I do that? Because they are nested so I'm not sure on how to do it. I tried doing

```
for key, value in stats['playerStatSummaries'].items():
    if key['playerStatSummaryType'] == "Unranked":
        # do something
```

But that didn't work, so; that's it, thanks for any help you can provide :)

Comment: Essentially, for your "CoopVsAI" question, you would access it as `stats['playerStatSummaries'][1]['aggregatedStats']['totalChampionKills']`. I am not 100% sure if that translates to the same way you should access this in Python, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"playerStatSummaries"` holds `list` value and not `dict`. Hence your `for` loop should be like:

```
#         v  This will be `dict` object
for player_stat_summary in stats['playerStatSummaries']:
    if player_stat_summary['playerStatSummaryType'] == "Unranked":
        # Do Something

        # player_stat_summary['aggregatedStats']['totalChampionKills']
        # For accessing the value you require
```

Comment: Well, it worked, I don't know why I always have problems with dictionaries, still learning how to handle them :P Btw, edit the IF to match the for loop name.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `stats` as

```
stats ={"summonerId": 24244,
"playerStatSummaries": [

    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "CAP5x5",
        "wins": 20,
        "modifyDate": 1453305771000,
        "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalChampionKills": 308,
            "totalMinionKills": 4985,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 36,
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 466,
            "totalAssists": 255
        }
    },
    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "CoopVsAI",
        "wins": 34,
        "modifyDate": 1453305771000,
        "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalChampionKills": 394,
            "totalMinionKills": 2741,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 57,
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 146,
            "totalAssists": 336
        }
    },
    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "CoopVsAI3x3",
        "wins": 1,
        "modifyDate": 1453305771000,
        "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalChampionKills": 6,
            "totalMinionKills": 69,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 2,
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 0,
            "totalAssists": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "RankedTeam3x3",
        "wins": 0,
        "losses": 0,
        "modifyDate": 1353893998000,
        "aggregatedStats": { }
    },
    {
        "playerStatSummaryType": "RankedTeam5x5",
        "wins": 0,
        "losses": 0,
        "modifyDate": 1354061714000,
        "aggregatedStats": { }
    }
    ]
}
```

The following will work

```
for stat in stats['playerStatSummaries']:
    if(stat["playerStatSummaryType"] == 'CoopVsAI'):
        print stat["aggregatedStats"]['totalChampionKills']
```

Comment: This also worked, sadly I can only select one correct answer, thanks for the input anyway man!

Comment: No issues, glad that I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

"playerStatSummaries"  This is a list of internal objects, why do you not read directly as a list of elements?

```
In [9]: a[1]
Out[9]: 
{'aggregatedStats': {'totalAssists': 336,
  'totalChampionKills': 394,
  'totalMinionKills': 2741,
  'totalNeutralMinionsKilled': 146,
  'totalTurretsKilled': 57},
 'modifyDate': 1453305771000,
 'playerStatSummaryType': 'CoopVsAI',
 'wins': 34}
```

If you need a deeper level is the same operation

```
In [12]: a[1]['aggregatedStats']['totalChampionKills']
Out[12]: 394
```